# Как передать русский язык в клавиатуру вк чат-бота?

Tags: python, вконтакте

начал разбираться с клавиатурой для чат ботов вк, вот мой код:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import json


def write_message(user_id, msg, keyboard=False):
    if keyboard == False:
        vk_session.method('messages.send', {'user_id': user_id, 'message': msg})
    else:
        vk_session.method('messages.send', {'user_id': user_id, 'message': msg, 'keyboard': str(json.dumps(keyboard))})


KEYBOARD_STEP_1 = {
    'one_time': False,
    'buttons': [[{
        'action': {
            'type': 'text',
            'payload': json.dumps({'buttons': '1'}),
            'label': 'Предыдущая',
        },
        'color': 'negative'
    },
    {
        'action': {
            'type': 'text',
            'payload': json.dumps({'buttons': '2'}),
            'label': 'Pred',
        },
        'color': 'primary'
    }
    ]]`введите сюда код`
}

write_message(user_id, message, KEYBOARD_STEP_1)
```

На выходе получаю такое:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как правильно передать строку, чтобы правильно отобразились русские символы?

Comment: Версия питона какая?

Comment: А вы бы не могли скинуть весь код? Без токена, конечно) А то вот всё мучаюсь, ошибка 911 по типу: неправильный формат клавиатуры. Буду невероятно благодарен)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

вот так должно заработать

```
keyboard = {
    'one_time': False,
    'buttons': [[{
        'action': {
            'type': 'text',
            'payload': json.dumps({'buttons': '1'}),
            'label': 'Предыдущая',
        },
        'color': 'negative'
    },
    {
        'action': {
            'type': 'text',
            'payload': json.dumps({'buttons': '2'}),
            'label': 'Pred',
        },
        'color': 'primary'
    }
    ]]
}
keyboard = json.dumps(keyboard, ensure_ascii=False).encode('utf-8')
keyboard = str(keyboard.decode('utf-8'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте кодировку `UTF-7` вместо `UTF-8`. Когда я писал на `HTML` выходило примерно тоже, пока кодировку не поменял. Может и вам поможет.